# String format for getting the day of the month without leading zero

Tags: c#, datetime, string-formatting

I'm trying to use string formatting on a `DateTime` object in C# to get the day of the month without leading zeros.

After some searching I found [some documentation for DateTime formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), which shows that I should be able to call:

```
dateTime.ToString("d");
```

to get the value I'm after, however when I tried it, instead of receiving a number like `28`, the output was: `3/28/2013`.

After a bit more searching I found documentation for the [Standard Date and Time String Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).

Both sets of formats make use of the `"d"` format, but it is apparent by the results that the standard string format is taking precedence over the custom string format.

**Is there a way to specify which formatting is desired?**

For code consistency I'd prefer to write:

```
a = dateTime.ToString(...some format...);
b = dateTime.ToString(...some format...);
```

rather than

```
a = dateTime.ToString(...some format...);
b = dateTime.Day.ToString();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A single character is understood to be a [Standard Date and Time Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx), in this case the "Short date pattern".

You need to prefix a single character custom format string with `%` for it to be interpreted as a custom one:

```
dateTime.ToString("%d");
```

This is described on the page you linked to, under [Using Single Custom Format Specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers) (which describes the `%` custom format specifier).

Comment: +1 This explains why if you add a space after `d` you get the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `ToString` method use the format as a custom format string instead of a standard format string by adding an empty literal into the format:

```
dateTime.ToString("''d")
```

Comment: Nice workaround - using an empty inner string literal. I still prefer the documented `%` for this.

Comment: @Oded: Note: This *is* documented, just not for this specific use. And I prefer this to the `" d"` or `"d "` also proposed in the documentation... :)